# AS3 Mobile take picture CameraRoll

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, camera, drawing

Using AS3 to take a picture with the iOS camera. I have it all working, but my picture is ALWAYS landscape. I have the app set to portrait and take the picture with the IMAGE MediaType, which is also in Portrait mode when I take the picture.

Any ideas? Should I just scale and rotate accordingly or is there something to get around this?

Also- if anyone has a small demo of painting on BitmapData/pictures taken that would be appreciated as well :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I simple just checked the width and height of the image, rotated and scaled accordingly.